# Infinite loop warning in vue table rendering

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, infinite-loop

I tried calling a function while rendering a table, and based on condition in the function i assigned that value and displayed it using string interpolation, but i am getting infinite loop error.

Below is url for code

jsfiddle.net/amit_bhadale/5kct0au1/2/

Below is function

```
checkData(day, time){
        let that = this
        let result = this.serverData.some(a=>{
            if(a.Day === day && a.Time === time){
                that.cellId = a.id 
                // This is giving infinite loop error

                // if i chnage it to this then it works
                // that.cellId = 'Some normal string'
            }
            return (a.Day === day && a.Time === time)
        })
        return result
    }
```

HTML part

```
<table>
        <tr v-for="(time, i) in time" :key="i">
            <td v-for="(day, j) in day" :key="j">
                <span v-if="checkData(day, time)">

                </span>
                <span v-else>
                    No data in this cell
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: You can see the infinite loop warning in console. Thanks.

Comment: While JSFiddles are very welcome for helping others to reproduce your issue, it is generally expected for you to put your code (at least the parts that seem to cause the error) in your question itself as well.

Comment: @DelenaMalan Thanks for letting me know. i  have updated the question

Comment: i think this is the reason for the warning: `that.cellId = a.id ` as you modify a property possible to trigger a rendercycle within a rendercycle

Comment: @Estradiaz How can we tackle this?

Comment: dont share `cellId` -> easiest way is to put your span pair into a separate component and pass day and time as prop then you have no conflict with the `cellId` also the v-if can be replaced by a computed prop then etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont update props multiple times with different values within in render cycle.
To seperate those you can just put it into a single component:
e.g.:

```js
{
  props: ['time', 'day', 'serverData'],
  computed: {
    cellValue(){
      let val = "No data in this cell"
      this.serverData.some(a=>{
        if(a.Day === this.day && a.Time === this.time){
            val = a.id;return true;
        }
      })
      return val
     }
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <span>cellValue</span>
</template>
```